# Simplifying Visual Studio Find result format

Tags: visual-studio, findall

I want to simplify Visual Studio Find in Files result, and I found [a posting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/11/24/did-you-know-you-can-customize-how-search-results-are-displayed-in-the-find-results-window-363.aspx).
And I found it is not quite satisfactory.

Is there a way to display partial portion of directory in find result window?

ie)

```
x:\users\myname\project\solution_home\project1_home\src\project1.cpp
x:\users\myname\project\solution_home\project1_home\src\helper.cpp
x:\users\myname\project\solution_home\project2_home\src\helper.cpp
```

into

```
\project1_home\project1.cpp
\project1_home\helper.cpp
\project2_home\helper.cpp
```

IMHO, filename alone is not enough to distinguish important result, particulary in large soultion.
but, I want to eliminate certain part of directory path being repeated in every single result.

I wish there would be directory depth designation in $d format string.

ie)

```
$0d : file's directory
$1d : parent directory
$2d : parent of parent 
... etc
```

Is there any extension and/or technique to do this?

PS: sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1):

I have something of a hack for this problem: map the local path to a drive. For example:

```
> subst Y: x:\users\myname\project\solution_home
```

Your Find Results will then be:

```
Y:\project1_home\project1.cpp
Y:\project1_home\helper.cpp
Y:\project2_home\helper.cpp
```

N.B. It has the side effect of breaking the CodeLens Team indicators (which must be a bug).